# Splash screen / animation between fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-animation

I tried to realize **splash screen animation like in News Digest application**. Luckily I found nice example in GitHub  Click [here](https://github.com/ykabaran/NewsDigestSplash) but in this example as you can see when circles to merge together and disappear opened `ContentView` which is a picture.

They used these lines.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
// now that our data is loaded we can initialize the content view
mContentView = new ContentView(context);
// add the content view to the background
mMainView.addView(mContentView, 0);
```

I have my MainActivity layout view. **How to show main layout view instead of these picture?!** I want to see main_layout view after circles to merge together and disappear. I used these code below but it didn`t help me. You will see few seconds black screen and only after that Main Layout. But its not what i want. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?! What i need to change?!

```
// Start your app main activity
startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
// close splashScreen activity
finish();
```

**Picture is here** Click [here](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/e766cb8edd99c19c6e357bb0a439c327a12bb037/687474703a2f2f692e696d67626f782e636f6d2f32756a69544579682e676966)

Answer (score 1):

YOu could use one Activity.. if you are not doing anything specifically on the splash screen, or you really dont mind using one activity you can do this..

```
//after splash screen is done flirting with the user,i.e circle effects
View v = Activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_layout, null); 
mContentView = new ContentView(context); // put your preferred context
mMainView.addView(v, 0);
```

you can put it well in onresume-(the waiting and animation).. ayt.. and maybe do your splash stuff in oncreate

actually i do not know that library. i cant really tell the parameters, but if you want the effect or ouput as the picture you linked this should pretty well do it for you..

let me know wassup

Comment: @Elitz hello! let me explain you. Actually in that project only what you need to use is SplashView.java document in which described animation but it`s better dont touch it =) Main changes its better to to in MainActivity. java document. Can you tell me what getLayoutInflater method done? And what what will be in ContentView. Before it was imageview as i said. But in our case how to said that it must me main_layout.view? As i understand such things they wrote in ContentView.java document. I really dont know what to do and i think you are my last hope! =)

Comment: Heloo @NurzhanNogerbek , ok i see, yeah getLayoutInflater() Instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding View objects, by means of layoutInflater class, get it now sir?, well the contentView from my understanding is the library's custom view which takes context, that is `yourclass.this` or `getApplicationContext()`, etc.. as you did in your sample.. yes yes, from the definition of what i said about the layoutinflater method, what it does is it inflates an xml file as a view, okay, and before you were using Imageview, and an imageview extends View, so to sum it up it is still  a view

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek , i am continuing, the getLayoutInflater method inflates it to a view which was in my code `v` so take it that v is an image okay?, now you add the image to your ContentView.. so what you will do is follow their procedure and use your main activity and code it, and when you want to show your main layout use the code i provided and picture it as an image.. okay.. let me know if you understand me.. hope my english is clear enough to you

Comment: Sadly i don`t understand all things what you said. I just make my first steps in android programming and i think its better to explane by examples if you can of course! Anyway thanks for find time for me. As i see you are pro, can you look to the library to this document?! https://github.com/ykabaran/NewsDigestSplash/blob/master/src/com/yildizkabaran/newsdigestsplash/MainActivity.java

Comment: do you want me to put your respective code in the same or explain it to you@NurzhanNogerbek